# The right using of Lightning helpers

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Could someone explain what is the correct way of using Lightning helpers? Is that any place where I can find best practices how to move code from the controller to the helper? Sometimes I see in js controller methods that call methods directly from the helpers without any additional logic inside of controller method. But sometimes developers move part of code to the helpers.

Comment: It kinda opinion based answer, but will write my thought,

If it's not reusable code, I don't put that in Helper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Use Controllers to listen to user events and other events like component, application events. But delegate business logic to helper.
- Do similar delegation in all Renderer functions (render, rerender and so on).
- Anytime you need to call one controller function from another controller function, move that logic to Helper.

Here is a article to give you a very good idea about helper.js vs controller.js.

[Understanding JavaScript Controllers Versus Helpers In Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/understanding-javascript-controllers-versus-helpers-lightning-components.html)

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is that same instances of the component share one helper. This is important when you're doing things like `action.setStorable()` in your `helper` and you have same data that should only be fetched once, then all instances of your component (except the first) won't go to server to fetch it.

Generally, it's best to `handleClick\handleChange\handleLoad` in your controller and then `execute/fetch/get` it in your helper. This is the pattern that made the most sense to me so far.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer from Rajesh is good here. To re-enforce that and add some non-SF terminology to it, it's helpful to think in terms of the Model-View-Controller pattern.

If you try to draw boxes around a Lightning Component to decide what's the Model, what's the View, and what's the Controller, then I think it ends up like this:

**View**: The markup

**Controller**: The controller.js, this translates front-end commands (e.g. click, hover, etc.) into more abstract commands that can be sent to the Model

**Model**: The helper.js, and the Apex Controller. This is the business logic, storage, etc. It doesn't really know about the UI. The UI should be able to change without this changing. So, for example, if you had a text input in your markup and you changed it for some radio buttons, *the model should never have to change*. In Lightning, controller.js might have to change but helper.js should not. (Unfortunately, Lightning's abstractions are currently a bit leaky here so you might have to use Apex to get your list of options. You could do this by introducing a new component which just fetches those options, gets included in the markup, and doesn't break MVC in this particular component)

It's easy to get confused about MVC:

1. Lightning uses "controller" in it's terminology and it doesn't
   correspond to the C in MVC
2. There doesn't have to be a 1:1 correlation between boxes in your framework (Lightning) and boxes in the MVC diagram e.g. the Model is implemented by more than one thing in Lightning
3. It exists at multiple levels at the same time. `<lightning:input>` is MVC, and so is your custom component that uses it
4. Everyone's heard of MVC, so it's assumed that everyone understands it. But, it's worth thinking a bit more about it. Have a watch of this from Uncle Bob Martin: https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4?t=27m30s

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than trivial logic ends up being broken up into methods that call other methods and the lack of that capability in controllers (but it being allowed in helpers) makes controllers often end up delegating all their work to a corresponding helper method.

I sure hope there is some strong benefit of this controller/helper pattern to the framework or some categories of components because I've found it in general to just result in more boiler plate code to have to write and refactor - not elegant.